# How to capture binary stdout of a console exe run from Powershell?

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to get Powershell to read the stdout of an exe into a byte[] instead of the usual text processed array of lines?

Best I've been able to do is this:

```
cmd /c foo.exe > foo.tmp
$b = [io.file]::readallbytes('foo.tmp')
del foo.tmp
```

Yucky, not to mention it is not streamable. Any better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got some info from the PowerShell team.  The short answer is that unfortunately, it is not easy.  :-(

The medium length answer is: http://poshcode.org/2175.

The long answer is: [Capture and Redirect Binary Process Output](http://www.pavleck.net/powershell-cookbook/ch02.html)

Comment: Thanks for following up. I was hoping it wouldn't require the same yucky stuff I had to do in C#, but it's nice to have the code already available on poshcode. Also: you just made Lee Holmes a sale. I'm picking up the 2nd ed of that book. :)

Comment: Both of the links in this post are now dead :(

Comment: Here's an updated link to the PowerShell Cookbook book - https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/powershell-cookbook-4th/9781098101596/